# Unable to run Postman Newman command in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, postman, pipeline, newman

I am trying to run a series of Postman test in my Azure build pipeline but keep getting errors that Newman is not installed, I have checked by going to the exact location and running the Newman commands without any issue. My screenshots show I have implemented them and the errors.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you have used commands as call `newman run`.
Instead use:

```
newman run collection.json -e environment_file.json --reporters cli,junit,htmlextra --reporter-junit-export junitReport.xml
```

It works for me from Azure Pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

This is what mine looks like in YAML - if you click on 'View YAML' on the top right you can see the difference. I think you have this 'call' word that shouldn't be there.

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Run newman tests
    inputs:
      script: 'newman run "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.e2eCollectionPath }}" -e "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.e2eEnvironmentPath }}" --reporters cli,junit --reporter-junit-export $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/report.xml'
```